# Can't evaluate the heat transfer coefficient of a straight pipe in OpenModelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to get used to the `Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation`. I want to evaluate the heat transfer coefficient of a straight pipe using the function `kc_overall`. I tried to followthe `UsersGuide` example. I'm not sure I understood how to write it and which inputs I have to use. Here's my code:

```
model Heat_tranfer_calcul
 Modelica.SIunits.MassFlowRate M_FLOW=0.3 "input mass flow rate";
Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall_IN_con IN_con(d_hyd=13e-3,L=15);
Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall_IN_var IN_var(cp=4184,eta=8.9e-4,lambda=0.6,rho=1000) ;
equation
Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall(IN_con,IN_var,M_FLOW)
end Heat_tranfer_calcul;
```

I also tried to get the fluid properties directly from the `Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater`.
If someone could help me to uderstand how the function works that would be really helpful.

Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `kc_overall` only takes two arguments — the records `IN_con` and `IN_var`. The mass flow rate must be specified through `IN_var` so your code should be:

```
model Heat_tranfer_calcul
  Modelica.SIunits.MassFlowRate M_FLOW=0.3 "input mass flow rate";
  Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall_IN_con IN_con(d_hyd=13e-3,L=15);

  Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall_IN_var IN_var(cp=4184,eta=8.9e-4,lambda=0.6,rho=1000, m_flow=M_FLOW);
equation
Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall(IN_con,IN_var);
end Heat_tranfer_calcul;
```

By the way, it is good Modelica coding practice to use lowercase letters for variable names, that is `m_flow` instead of `M_FLOW`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer and advice, the code is running but I have two questions. The first one is where can I find which variable are in the records IN_con and IN_var so I know which I need to specify. The second one is in my code, I created output variables for the Prandtl Pr, the Nusselt Nu and the Reynolds Re numbers and one for the heat transfer coefficient kc.  How can I know the order for the function : for example is it `(Pr, Re, Nu, kc)=Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.StraightPipe.kc_overall(IN_con,IN_var);` or `(kc,Pr,Re,Nu)`. I couldn'f find it in the doc of the function